# Align image and text in center in GridView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to align image and text in the center, it works when text is small but when i have large text then everything changes. I am using GridView which has 3 items on each row..

```
Widget buildItems(BuildContext context, String impagepath, String modulename) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,      
      children: <Widget>[
         Expanded(          
          child: CustomButtonWidget(
                        image: impagepath,
                        size: 100,
                        borderWidth: 5,
                        onTap: () {}
                      ),

        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,              
              child: Text("${selectlang.getAlbum(modulename, lang_selection)}"),
            ),
          ],
        ) 

     
      ],
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`CrossAxisAlignment`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html) property of Column` widget

Use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,` in your `Column` widgets

```
Widget buildItems(BuildContext context, String impagepath, String modulename) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,     
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
      children: <Widget>[
         Expanded(          
          child: CustomButtonWidget(
                        image: impagepath,
                        size: 100,
                        borderWidth: 5,
                        onTap: () {}
                      ),

        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,              
              child: Text("${selectlang.getAlbum(modulename, lang_selection)}"),
            ),
          ],
        ) 

     
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: It gives me error. RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#cab96 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Column

Answer (score 0):

use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` inside column widget.

Comment: Thanks i tried that option, but if you see the image few have Circle and few have oval around it due to text size. I am trying to make it constant circle and text across all images.